# ERROR: Could not build wheels for cvxpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, visual-studio, cvxpy

I have encountered below issue when installing the CVXPY, I have also downloaded the lasted version of visual studio but seems not working either.

```
    >       C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730:
    > UserWarning:
    >           Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    >           Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    >           numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    >           the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    >         return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    >       error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio":
    > https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    >       {}
    >       {}
    >       ----------------------------------------
    >       ERROR: Failed building wheel for scs
    >       Running setup.py clean for scs
    >     Failed to build cvxpy ecos scs
    >     ERROR: Could not build wheels for cvxpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I had to create a new environment and install for it to work. Go to Anaconda Prompt, and do:

1. `conda create your_env_name`
2. `conda activate your_env_name`
3. `conda install -c conda-forge cvxpy`
4. `conda install spyder`

I use Spyder for my work. I had to install Spyder in the new environment as in step 4. I could not find a work around to use the existing Spyder to work for both environments.