# Error "failed building wheel for cvxpy" encountered when attempting to install CVXPY

Tags: python, installation, pip, failed-installation, cvxpy

I've encountered the error below while attempting to install the [convex optimization library `CVXPY`](https://www.cvxpy.org/). I previously encountered [this (distinct) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62082852/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-cvxpy-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-installe), and was able to rectify it by updating my `pip` installation with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.

```bash
Building wheels for collected packages: cvxpy
  Building wheel for cvxpy (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for cvxpy (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [551 lines of output]
      <string>:225: ResourceWarning: unclosed file <_io.TextIOWrapper name='READ                                     ME.md' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
      ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug/cvxpy
      copying cvxpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug/cvx                                     py

      ...

      
      running build_ext
      building '_cvxcore' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug/cvxpy
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug/cvxpy/cvxcore
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug/cvxpy/cvxcore/python
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug/cvxpy/cvxcore/src
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -Og -Wall -fPIC -Icvxpy/                                     cvxcore/src/ -Icvxpy/cvxcore/python/ -Icvxpy/cvxcore/include/ -I/cvmfs/ara.opens                                     ciencegrid.org/trunk/centos7/misc_build/include/python3.9d -I/tmp/pip-build-env-                                     vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c cvxpy/cvxcore                                     /python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug/cvxpy/cvx                                     core/python/cvxcore_wrap.o -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-unused-pa                                     rameter
      In file included from /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/si                                     te-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:0,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/si                                     te-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/si                                     te-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                       from cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:2846:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning is a GCC extensi                                     on [enabled by default]
       #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
        ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecate                                     d NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSIO                                     N" [-Wcpp]
      In file included from /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/si                                     te-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:21:0,
                       from /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/si                                     te-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                       from cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:2846:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h: In function ‘int _import_array()’:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:640:23: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[0])
                             ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1492:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_                                     GetNDArrayCVersion’
         if (NPY_VERSION != PyArray_GetNDArrayCVersion()) {
                            ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:640:23: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[0])
                             ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1495:39: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_                                     GetNDArrayCVersion’
                    (int) NPY_VERSION, (int) PyArray_GetNDArrayCVersion());
                                             ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1195:25: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betw                                     een pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[211])
                               ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1498:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_                                     GetNDArrayCFeatureVersion’
         if (NPY_FEATURE_VERSION > PyArray_GetNDArrayCFeatureVersion()) {
                                   ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1195:25: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betw                                     een pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[211])
                               ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1501:47: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_                                     GetNDArrayCFeatureVersion’
                    (int) NPY_FEATURE_VERSION, (int) PyArray_GetNDArrayCFeatureV                                     ersion());
                                                     ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1192:25: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betw                                     een pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[210])
                               ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1509:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_G                                     etEndianness’
         st = PyArray_GetEndianness();
              ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx: In function ‘int type_match(int, in                                     t)’:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1135:25: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betw                                     een pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[191])
                               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:3443:12: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_EquivTypenums’
           return PyArray_EquivTypenums(actual_type, desired_type);
                  ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyArrayObject* obj_to_                                     array_no_conversion(PyObject*, int)’:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1135:25: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betw                                     een pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[191])
                               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:3455:29: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_EquivTypenums’
                                   PyArray_EquivTypenums(array_type(input), type                                     code)))
                                   ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyArrayObject* obj_to_                                     array_allow_conversion(PyObject*, int, int*)’:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1135:25: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betw                                     een pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[191])
                               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:3491:29: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_EquivTypenums’
                                   PyArray_EquivTypenums(array_type(input),typec                                     ode)))
                                   ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:769:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[69])
                              ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:89:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_FromAn                                     y’
               PyArray_FromAny(m, PyArray_DescrFromType(type), min, max, \
               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:3498:16: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_FROMANY’
             py_obj = PyArray_FROMANY(input, typecode, 0, 0, NPY_DEFAULT);
                      ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:697:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[45])
                              ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:89:28: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_Descr                                     FromType’
               PyArray_FromAny(m, PyArray_DescrFromType(type), min, max, \
                                  ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:3498:16: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_FROMANY’
             py_obj = PyArray_FROMANY(input, typecode, 0, 0, NPY_DEFAULT);
                      ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyArrayObject* make_co                                     ntiguous(PyArrayObject*, int*, int, int)’:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:769:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[69])
                              ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:188:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_FromA                                     ny’
               PyArray_FromAny(op, PyArray_DescrFromType(type), min_depth, \
               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:3522:33: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_ContiguousFromObject’
             result = (PyArrayObject*) PyArray_ContiguousFromObject((PyObject*)a                                     ry,
                                       ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:697:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[45])
                              ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:188:29: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_Desc                                     rFromType’
               PyArray_FromAny(op, PyArray_DescrFromType(type), min_depth, \
                                   ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:3522:33: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_ContiguousFromObject’
             result = (PyArrayObject*) PyArray_ContiguousFromObject((PyObject*)a                                     ry,
                                       ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyArrayObject* make_fo                                     rtran(PyArrayObject*, int*, int, int)’:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:889:25: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[109])
                               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:3549:33: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_FromArray’
             result = (PyArrayObject*) PyArray_FromArray(ary, ary->descr, NPY_FO                                     RTRAN);
                                       ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_Proble                                     mData_getV(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:841:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[93])
                              ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:118:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_New’
               PyArray_New(&PyArray_Type, nd, dims, typenum, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, N                                     ULL)
               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:7967:14: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_SimpleNew’
           array2 = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
                    ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_Proble                                     mData_getI(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:841:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[93])
                              ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:118:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_New’
               PyArray_New(&PyArray_Type, nd, dims, typenum, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, N                                     ULL)
               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:8010:14: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_SimpleNew’
           array2 = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
                    ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_Proble                                     mData_getJ(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:841:24: warning: ISO C++ forbids casting betwe                                     en pointer-to-function and pointer-to-object [-Wpedantic]
                PyArray_API[93])
                              ^
      /tmp/pip-build-env-vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core                                     /include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:118:9: note: in expansion of macro ‘PyArray_New’
               PyArray_New(&PyArray_Type, nd, dims, typenum, NULL, NULL, 0, 0, N                                     ULL)
               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/python/cvxcore_wrap.cxx:8053:14: note: in expansion of macro                                      ‘PyArray_SimpleNew’
           array2 = PyArray_SimpleNew(1, dims, NPY_DOUBLE);
                    ^
      gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -Og -Wall -fPIC -Icvxpy/                                     cvxcore/src/ -Icvxpy/cvxcore/python/ -Icvxpy/cvxcore/include/ -I/cvmfs/ara.opens                                     ciencegrid.org/trunk/centos7/misc_build/include/python3.9d -I/tmp/pip-build-env-                                     vp2obnop/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c cvxpy/cvxcore                                     /src/LinOpOperations.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39-pydebug/cvxpy/cvx                                     core/src/LinOpOperations.o -O3 -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wno-unused-pa                                     rameter
      In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/cassert:43:0,
                       from cvxpy/cvxcore/src/LinOpOperations.cpp:18:
      cvxpy/cvxcore/src/LinOpOperations.cpp: In function ‘Tensor get_kronl_mat(c                                     onst LinOp&, int)’:
      cvxpy/cvxcore/src/LinOpOperations.cpp:379:25: error: ‘IsRowMajor’ cannot b                                     e used as a function
         assert(!rh.IsRowMajor());
                               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/src/LinOpOperations.cpp: In function ‘Tensor get_vstack_mat(                                     const LinOp&, int)’:
      cvxpy/cvxcore/src/LinOpOperations.cpp:430:41: warning: comparison between                                      signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         assert(arg_idx <= lin.get_args().size());
                                               ^
      cvxpy/cvxcore/src/LinOpOperations.cpp: In function ‘Tensor get_hstack_mat(                                     const LinOp&, int)’:
      cvxpy/cvxcore/src/LinOpOperations.cpp:470:41: warning: comparison between                                      signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
         assert(arg_idx <= lin.get_args().size());
                                               ^
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem wit                                     h pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cvxpy
Failed to build cvxpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for cvxpy, which is required to install pyproject.                                     toml-based projects
```

I've redacted some of the output (some `copying ...` lines), which I believe to be irrelevant. [You can find the *full* output here.](https://pastebin.com/TDaEjp6G)

It seems that `pip` is attempting to build from source using the `.tar.gz` file, and not one of the available `whl` files. I've attempted to download the `manylinux` wheel, and install it with `pip instal XXX.whl`, but get the error `XXX.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`. The cluster is running CentOS 7 (Core).

Note that the target machine (an academic computing cluster) does not have Conda installed, and I am unable to install it. I'm attempting to run software which has a `CVXPY` dependency, and which requires access to data stored on this machine (which cannot be moved off of it). GCC is installed, fully functional, and exists at `/usr/bin/gcc`.

Comment: `does not have Conda installed, and I am unable to install it` <- are you aware that you don't need any sudo rights to install conda?

Comment: Which version of cvxpy are you trying to install? Which version of numpy do you have and what is your gcc version?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I'm attempting to install the latest version (`cvxpy 1.2`). It looks like `gcc 4.8.5` and `numpy 1.20.2` are installed.

Comment: It is a bit odd that it is not picking up one of the available [whl files](https://pypi.org/project/cvxpy/1.2.1/#files) then. It is missing from your posted output, but is `pip` actually attempting to install `cvxpy-1.2.1.tar.gz`

Comment: @FlyingTeller Yes, it looks like `pip` is trying to build from source, for some reason. I've tried downloading the Linux `whl` file directly from the attached link, and installing with `pip install xxx.whl`, but get the error `xxx.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform`. The machine is running `CentOS 7 (Core)`.

Comment: I just tried on a centos system with `ecos==2.0.10
numpy==1.23.2
osqp==0.6.2
qdldl==0.1.5
scipy==1.9.0
scs==3.2.0
pip==22.1.2` and it worked. Try to `pip install` those dependencies first and then install cvxpy

Comment: @FlyingTeller Unfortunately, it looks like I'm getting the same error.